# SimpleForm submit with "return" key

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Using the simple_form gem and rails I'm attempting to have a text_area (comment box) submit by only hitting the return key. Facebook has a similar feature and that's what I'm shooting for. Researching online hasn't produced much and I'm fairly new to Javascript still. Any suggestions?

Form Partial

```
<%= simple_form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
    <!-- Error messages -->
    <% if @comment.errors.any? %> 
    <div class="error_messages">
        <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- Comment Text Area -->
    <span class="field" id: "textArea">
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Comment...', rows: 3, class: 'story-comment' %><br/>
    </span>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <span class="actions" id: "formSubmit">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Post Comment", class: "btn btn-default pull-right"%>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

Form output html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/statuses/91/comments" class="simple_form new_comment" id="new_comment" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vSpHph2PkCPAiItJ8UJFZh8grkanJA4VQxsdcxrcvig=" /></div>
    <!-- Error messages -->
    <!-- Comment Text Area -->
    <span class="field" id: "textArea">
        <textarea class="story-comment" id="comment_content" name="comment[content]" placeholder="Comment..." rows="3">
</textarea><br/>
    </span>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <span class="actions" id: "formSubmit">
        <input class="btn btn btn-default pull-right" name="commit" type="submit" value="Post Comment" />
    </span>
</form>
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
 $('#textArea').keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#formSubmit').submit();
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: 1) Your formSubmit is not a form - you need a form to call .submit() - you need to do click() on a button
2) what does the rendered HTML look like 3) what errors are in the console if any?

Comment: 1) Not 100% sure how to get you the rendered HTML. 2) No errors in console. 3) formSubmit is just an id I added. I'm fairly advanced with rails but I'm not familiar with javascript best practices, so admittedly, that part may be completely wrong.

Comment: View-source to see html. Text area needs form tag with an action to submit

Comment: @mplungjan thanks. Added rendered HTML. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit the FORM not the button and you need to access the textarea's ID

Try

```
$('#comment_content').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('#new_comment').submit();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You are not telling us all there is. For example IDs must be unique and the IDs must match your script

Comment: I came back to this, I'm assuming I had a syntax error in my JS that was keeping this from firing. It works fine now and I copied your code straight. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Please delete the first comment for future visitors